# WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive specify action

Tags: spring-ws

I am calling a webservice using WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive. 
As argument, I am passing a the soap xml as source that actually contains soap header and body.

But the server complains that, invalid action name.

So how to specify action name in the WebServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceive method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one of those `sendSourceAndReceive` which applies a `WebServiceMessageCallback` arg. And use `SoapActionCallback`:

```
Result result = new DOMResult();

template.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(
    new StringSource("<content xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org\"/>"),
    new SoapActionCallback("http://tempuri.org/SOAPAction"),
    result);
```